# Paho javascript client + mosquitto Websockets + Tls

Tags: ssl, websocket, mosquitto

I've beend trying to add security layers for mosquitto broker for a while now and I need some help.

I configured my broker with this configuration :

```
...
#logs


#authentication

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
allow_anonymous false

#user
user mosquitto

#broker settings
require_certificate false
listener 8081
protocol websockets
http_dir /var/www/html
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mosquitto-certificate-authority.crt
```

This is what the log outputs:

```
1631281308: mosquitto version 2.0.12 starting
1631281308: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1631281308: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8081.
1631281308: mosquitto version 2.0.12 running
```

I generated my certificates acording to this site: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=287326. I believe it's not a problem with the certificates as everything went right when testing with mosquitto-clients (commenting the protocol websockets on .conf file).

I uploaded a test code from this site https://jpmens.net/2014/07/03/the-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-gets-websockets-support/ on my nginx service to test the connection with secure websockets but all it gives me is "Connection failed: AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.Retrying".

Can you guys help me out please?

Comment: Is this related to _programming_? Because I can't see any programming problem here.

Comment: I could have included all the html,css and java in here but for the sake of simplicity I left in the last link.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated your own certificates, you will need import the CA cert into the browser so it knows to trust it to sign the brokers certificate.

Unlike with a webpage, the browser will not prompt you to trust the certificate when the connection is triggered by JavaScript, you need to do it manually before trying to connect.

Comment: I imported my certificate in google chrome in privacy settings, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, but it will depend on which certificate you imported into which section. You need to import the CA cert as a trusted CA

Comment: I'll look up to it and give an update. Thanks

Comment: I think I did it right. From what I searched ,it is suposed to give you a warning when it's not setup correctly. I do not have any warning so I am assuming that is not the cause of the error I described. Thank you anyways.

Comment: As I said in the answer when the connection is triggered from Javascript the browser will NOT warn/ask you about the certificate, it will just fail

Comment: Okay, I have configured nginx to do an https connection. Even though i got a google warning about the self-signed certificate, it said on the developer console (in security) that the connection was encrypted and i still got the same error.